# T4 Template inside Directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, t4

There is a Class Library in my solution called "**XMLClassGenerator**" inside a Folder (Visual studio solution folder) called "HelperModules".

the "**XMLClassGenerator**" Module which has a `T4 Template` which scans through the entire solution (i have around 23 class libraries in different solution folders ) for files which ends as "**config.xml**" and generates classes to manipulate XML data without hard coding keys.

Suspected T4 Template code

```
    var hostServiceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
    var dte = (DTE)hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));


    foreach (Project project in dte.Solution)
    {
       var items =    ((Project)project).ProjectItems.GetEnumerator();;
       while (items.MoveNext())
       {
          var item = (ProjectItem)items.Current;
          //Recursion to get all ProjectItems
          projectItems.Add(GetFiles(item));
       }
    }

    string GetFiles(ProjectItem item)
    {
        var itemFullPath = string.Empty;

        int g = item.FileCount;

        if (item.FileCount > 0)
            itemFullPath = item.FileNames[1];

      ....
      .... 
    }
```

the **`item.FileNames[1]`**  returns null in my current setup.

But if i move the **XMLClassGenerator** module to the solution root **everything works perfectly**.

How to get the same behavior when the **XMLClassGenerator** module is inside a solution folder.

Comment: Not repro on my machine, VS 2015. Do you have another machine to verify?

Comment: I don't have vs2015 right now to test it, i am using vs 2013 with Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll is 7.1060.71

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `foreach (Project project in dte.Solution)` iterates through Subfolders in the solutions instead of Actual Projects in the solution

so the code to get list of project should be like below

```
    private List<Project> GetAllProjects()
    {
        List<Project> lst = new List<Project>();

        var hostServiceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
        var DTE = (DTE)hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));

        foreach (Project proj in DTE.Solution.Projects) {
            if (proj.Kind == Constants.vsProjectKindSolutionItems) {
                lst.AddRange(GetSubProjects(proj.ProjectItems));
            } else {
                lst.Add(proj);
            }
        }
        return lst;
    }

    private List<Project> GetSubProjects(ProjectItems pis)
    {
        List<Project> lst = new List<Project>();
        foreach (ProjectItem pi in pis) {
            if (pi.Kind == Constants.vsProjectItemKindSolutionItems) {
                lst.Add(pi.SubProject);
            } else if (pi.Kind == Constants.vsProjectKindSolutionItems) {
                lst.AddRange(GetSubProjects(pi.ProjectItems));
            }
        }
        return lst;
    }
```